# IIS 8.5 asp.net impersonation and directory permissions

Tags: iis-8

I'm trying to set up an web app in IIS 8.5.  The web app uses asp.net impersonation so that I can get the connected users details, username, fullname etc.  Everything works fine locally with my admin account however when trying to connect remotely (intranet environment) with a standard user account I'm getting a windows security dialogue box pop up.

I added the user account to the directory with read rights which I expected to work, however, I'm still getting the popup.  Obviously I'm not doing something correctly.  Would someone explain what permissions I need to add to the directory so that a user does not get the security popup when visiting the site?

Answer (score 0):

Check that the domain name of the web app is in the Intranet Zone (or a Trusted Site) for the user's browser, and that Automatic Logon is enabled for sites in that Zone. This can be found in Internet Settings on the client browser.

For more information on configuring client browsers for automatic logon: 
https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd572939(v=office.13).aspx